# не работает tensorflow, выдает ошибку: ImportError: DLL load failed:

Tags: python, установка, tensorflow

пишу в коде для проверки работоспособности tensorflow: `import tensorflow as tf`

выдает:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
        _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
        _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
        return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
        return _load(spec)
    ImportError: DLL load failed: Произошел сбой в программе инициализации библиотеки динамической компоновки (DLL).

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "d:/Программирование/Deep learning/detection_symbols_MNIST.py", line 1, in <module>
        import tensorflow as tf
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 101,
    in <module>
        from tensorflow_core import *
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line
    40, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
        module = self._load()
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
        module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
        raise ImportError(msg)
    ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
        _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
        _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 242, in load_module
        return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
        return _load(spec)
    ImportError: DLL load failed: Произошел сбой в программе инициализации библиотеки динамической компоновки (DLL).


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

не знаю что делать;
решения проблемы искал, ничего не смог сделать;
версия `tensorflow: 2.1.0`;
помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Использовался ли пакет virtualenv при установке tensorflow?
P.S. см статью на Хабре: https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/450314/